# Python and unity webplayer

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

i have a nearly full developed program written in python it uses the Kivy framework which however does not employ a webplayer. 
I want to migrate it to a webplayer and decided to try it on unity with ironpython.
This however does not work since the webplayer has a limited subset not the full subset from .net.

Sadly the unity community has little interest in python and cannot really help with this.

So my question is: 
What else could i try?

could i write most code in python compile it to a library and access it from c# or has someone an other idea to integrate it with unity?

Is there a way at all with unity, if not what would you suggest then to make a python webplayer?

Note i want to use a platform which i can use to compile to mobilephones too thats why i did go with unity.